# There is a problem with \section alignment

Tags: sectioning, indentation, enumitem, sections-paragraphs

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents

\section{First}
\subsection{Problem}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Matter 1
\item Matter 2
\section{Second}
\subsection{Problem}
\item Matter 3
\section{Third}
\subsection{Aim}
\item Matter 4
\end{enumerate}
The End

\end{document}
```

[image]

Only the first `\section` has the problem. The others except the first are starting from the right. I could not find the problem. Can the first one start in the same align?

Comment: You're mixing `\section` outside of `enumerate` and inside of it -- this must 'fail' concerning the alignment. Better close the enumerate environment, then use `\section` again and then apply `\begin{enumerate} with `resume` option of enumerate in order to continue the old enumerate list

Comment: I would say, that the alignment of the 2nd section pair is wrong, not the first one

Comment: the section headings should never be inside the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way how `\section` etc. is defined and aligned conflicts with the list definitions and alignment of `enumerate` etc, thus 'section headings should never be inside a list' (citing David Carlisle).

I suggest to apply the resume feature of `enumitem` and using `\begin{enumerate}...\end{enumerate}` for the first occurence of that environment, thereby closing it, starting a new section or subsection and continuing the enumeration with `\begin{enumerate}[resume]...\end{resume}` for each of the consecutive sections etc.

If more sophisticated continuation of lists is requested, define a 'series' of enumerations that can be resumed with `series=foo` in the first occurence of this series and `resume=foo` for the enumerations that belong this series.

The following code does not apply `series`, however.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents

\section{First}
\subsection{Problem}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Matter 1
\item Matter 2
\end{enumerate}
\section{Second}
\subsection{Problem}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Matter 3
\end{enumerate}
\section{Third}
\subsection{Aim}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Matter 4
\end{enumerate}
The End

\end{document}
```

[image]